# How to add splash screen in flutter without setting random wait number

Tags: android, flutter, dart, mobile, splash-screen

```
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 3), () {
      Navigator.pushReplacement(
          context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const Home()));
    }
    );
  }
```

After 3 seconds I'm directed to my home screen, but I don't want this predefined time of 3 seconds, but according to the device's processing. How can I do this?

Comment: Remove Future.delayed. If you have your own custom logic, then after that logic is processed, then just call Navigator.pushReplacement(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const Home()));

Comment: Newer Android versions have an own system splash screen. Check out hoe to customize it. Besides that it is now considered bad practice to implement an own splash screen.